# Implementation ClientDetailsService (Spring Security OAuth2) for working with JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I developed a REST service and I want to add OAuth2. Do I understand correctly that clients in OAuth2 are trusted applications and the developers must register them such as in Intstagram or VK.com either Facebook ?

At the moment I create the clients in that way:

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
                .withClient("clientapp")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                    .secret("123456");
    }
```

But I want to create them dynamically and to save into the database. I have found the implementation by JBDC. But I want to do it using JPA(Hibernate).

Do I understand right that I need to:

1.Create the database schema

```
create table oauth_client_details (
client_id VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY,
resource_ids VARCHAR(256),
client_secret VARCHAR(256),
scope VARCHAR(256),
authorized_grant_types VARCHAR(256),
web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(256),
authorities VARCHAR(256),
access_token_validity INTEGER,
refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
additional_information VARCHAR(4096),
autoapprove VARCHAR(256)
);
```

2. Create the entity CustomClientDetails which implements

```
public interface ClientDetails extends Serializable
```

3. And to implement

```
public interface ClientDetailsService
```

4. And at last

```
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
                .withClientDetails(customClientDetailsService); 
        }
```

So using this way will I be able to create the clients dynamically using the repository and service layer?

Answer (score 1):

The way it works for me,
1. Model your JPA object with column names matching the oauth_client_details schema
2. Write ClientService class to perform CRUD operations on the OathClientDetails object
3. Change your ClientServerConfigure to make use of jdbc

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource);
}


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder() {
   return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(4);
}
```